# How do I prevent 'Publish Web' from overwriting config files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

When I publish my Asp.Net MVC website to the production server (via VS2008), the web.config & castle.xml files are overwritten. The content of these files is obviously different between my local dev environment and the production server.

How do I prevent these files from being published?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Visual Studio solution explorer, go to your web.config file's properties.  Make sure "Build Action" is "None" and "Copy to Output Directory" is "Do not copy".

If you ever want to update it in the future you'll have to do it manually or change "Build Action" back to "Content".  The next time you build (or publish) it will overwrite it.

Comment: Worth noting that this also stops the config file being copied to output folders for debugging.

Comment: That's correct.  The "Build Action" is to not do anything, so any sort of build won't copy it.  If you have never built then you won't have a .config file.  If you update the file in your project it won't update the build.  It could cause you to pull your hair out...

Answer (score 4):

1. Add this to project file (*.csproj):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. Delete your web.config **OR**:

Select web.config and change in Properties window:

```
    "Copy to Output Directory"="Do not copy"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding this exclusion:

```
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```

to the project file (.csproj or .vbproj), inside these nodes:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

and

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
```

See [Web Deployment: Excluding Files and Folders via the Web Application’s Project File](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-applications-project-file/).

Answer (score 0):

We use a Jenkins pipeline to deploy .Net Core/Framework apps to an ISS server.

One of the steps defines a Power Shell script that calls `MSBuild` with the specified project and publish profile.

Adding the `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment` tag to the Publish Profile script worked.

**WebDeploy-Staging.pubxml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- All the other tags excluded for brevity -->

    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>

  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
</Project>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Never publish directly from Visual Studio to a production server!**

Publish to a testing server for QA to look at, and then copy from QA to production (for an existing web site with no iis changes, it's just a matter of copying files).

Where I'm at, we also keep these published files under revision control separately, and so when QA signs off on a build the deployment process is simply checking out the files from source control on the production server.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point too.  I usually don't copy the web.config to the QA server either since it uses different configuration than during development.

Comment: I would add, never publish directly from Visual Studio to anywhere. Where I'm at, the build server builds everything and it also handles publishing; it publishes to a local folder and then rsyncs it to the Q&A server (on demand). Deployment to production is done manually by copying Q&A to production. Seriously though, the build server is the greatest invention since the wheel.

Comment: This answer might be good advice, but it does not attempt to answer the actual question.

Comment: This is a small open source project. I don't have a build server, nor QA :)

Comment: TeamCity is free for small projects, you could have your dev box be your build server.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html

No formatting of comments??

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with publishing to a production server? I put more trust in a click-to-publish system than in a human doing a manual copy-paste for every publish.