# Prevent web.config change on web deployment

Tags: c#, web-deployment

We have a web deployment package for an app developed in C#, when installed in IIS the web.config has several settings in it, for example:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="ReportFiles" value="http://localhost/ReportTemp/"/>
</appSettings>
```

A setting may get changed (for example ReportFiles above) at each site it is deployed and then if there is an update to the app we would install the latest web deployment package.

Unfortunately this overwrites all the settings that may have changed, back to the default. This means every time we update the application we have to take a copy of the web.config, do the update then copy it back.

Is there a way of stopping the web.config being updated once created? Or during the web deployment allowing the installer to see the existing settings and decide whether to keep?

Comment: Why don't you keep your app settings in a separate file `<appSettings configSource="Somefile.config"></appSettings>`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Web.config transforms

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

or this

[How do I prevent 'Publish Web' from overwriting config files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812905/how-do-i-prevent-publish-web-from-overwriting-config-files)

Comment: Sorry if I'm understanding this wrong but is this not a compile time operation? The problem I'm having is when I deploy to site we change some settings, then in the future when we go to update it overwrites these setting with the default web.config in the package

Answer (score 1):

I stole this from somewhere I can't remember.  Put this in a new blah.targets file and add `<Import Project="blah.targets" />` to your csproj file somewhere under `<Project>`.  It will make webdeploy not overwrite the existing web.config.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!--These UseMsDeployExe and AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest are relevant to the msdeploy, perhaps otherwise in the pubxml files-->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
        <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>OnAfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest</AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
    </PropertyGroup>    

    <!-- We do not want to OVERWRITE the web.config file if it is present at the destination -->
    <!-- We also don't want to delete it so we can't just exclude it -->
    <Target Name="ExcludeWebConfig">
        <Message Text="Excluding Web Config From Publish.  Be sure to manually deploy any new settings." Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipWebConfigDelete">
                <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
                <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
                <AbsolutePath>$(_DestinationContentPath)\\Web.config</AbsolutePath>
                <Apply>Destination</Apply>
            </MsDeploySkipRules>
            <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipWebConfigUpdate">
                <SkipAction>Update</SkipAction>
                <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
                <AbsolutePath>$(_DestinationContentPath)\\Web.config</AbsolutePath>
                <Apply>Destination</Apply>
            </MsDeploySkipRules>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="OnAfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest" DependsOnTargets="ExcludeWebConfig" />
</Project>
```

Comment: and I think I've seen that a specific (by-convention) special filename will allow this to get picked up without modifying csproj, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: This sounds like what I want, I put this into my project and published to create my web deployment package zip file.

This message appears in the output 'Excluding Web Config From Publish.  Be sure to manually deploy any new settings.', so I assume it worked.

When I go to 'Import Application' via IIS I still get the same issue, any changes to the web.config get overwritten with the default when deployed, any ideas?

Comment: I guess because the immediate destination is a new zip file which doesn't already include a previous version of that file to avoid overwriting.  The zip itself doesn't preserve the behavior.  You could add an `MsDeploySkipRules` for `AddChild` to omit it always.  And perhaps you could add a condition to only use that new rule when deploying to this certain target, so your dev/test/qa deploys work easier

Answer (score 1):

These answers are more correct and futureproof, however if you want to do a quick and dirty web deploy from visual studio and skip web.config or another file, simply hit the 'preview' button first and then uncheck the files you don;t want from the list before hitting publish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with database. Keep your report files in a table based on some id (like client Id or anything) and use from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change Build Action from Content to None and make sure that the Copy to Dir.. is set to Do not copy. This is true also for appsettings.json